# Gmail, Keyboard shortcut to view attachment

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts, gmail

Is there a keyboard shortcut to mimic clicking on the first attachment?  For instance to view a PDF?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I looked at that link above and did not find an answer.  I googled it and came up empty.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a built-in keyboard shortcut for this other than using tab to manually change keyboard focus to the attachment, which is pretty tedious.

If you're using Chrome and willing to install a browser extension, [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) allows you to select links using your keyboard and works on any website, not just Gmail. You do need to disable Gmail's default keyboard shortcuts first, as there are some conflicts, but Vimium's functionality more than makes up for it. I consider it indispensable for using the keyboard with a web browser.